# Deja-dup: Invalid data - SHA1 hash mismatch for file

Tags: deja-dup

I have backed up my data with deja-dup utility and made clean install of 12.04.
But when I tried to restore the back up I got this error:

```
invalid data - SHA1 hash mismatch for file:
 duplicity-full.20120508T105537Z.vol12.difftar.gz
 Calculated hash: 8ae69af39a566823309fae86142ae3a2af16358d
 Manifest hash: 6a332f406b0842f229e2122921c0e4c97c4f76bd
```

I tried to remove cache and perform manual restore with different options but it fails every time on same files. I put attention that those files are smaller then other. They are about 30Mb while all other files are 51Mb.

- Total size of backup is about 35Gb.
- Backup is stored on external USB drive with FAT file system.
- No encryption used

Is it some workaround exists?
Is it possible to exclude specific files from restore?

Any ideas?...  As you understand, I **REALLY NEED** this data!...

Thanks

Update:
@Nirmik, @Eliah Kagan:

I tried to restore from local directory and UbuntuOne as well. The same problem. I can restore some files but never succeeded to restore full backup. I tried to perform those actions with test backup of some small directory... the problem is consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you hit a known bug: deja-dup [bug 826389](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deja-dup/+bug/826389), [bug 487720](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/487720).

Quoting from the second link it seems that your data corruption is not given by hardware, but is completely software-related:

> This can happen when a volume file was not completely written to the backend before duplicity was interrupted (say, shutting down the machine or whatever). When duplicity resumes the backup next run, it will start with the next volume. The half-complete volume file will sit on the backend and cause this error later when restoring.
>
> You can manually recover from this by either restoring from your older backup sets or by restoring individual files that don't happen to be in the corrupted volume.

Two other guys from the first link says:

> There are two ways around this. You can try to restore from the backup from before the corrupted one. So try restoring from older backups.
>
> You can also try to avoid the specific volume by restoring all the files from the backup set except the ones in the corrupted volume.

and:

> Thank you very much. What I did was [duplicity --file-to-restore ....] and I restored the important files.

I've never used deja-dup or duplicity, but it seems that the most reasonable solution here is to automatically restore intact volumes with deja-dup, and then proceed with intact files inside a volume restoring them one by one with `duplicity --file-to-restore ...`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try transfering the data to a folder in your home directory e.g /Home/username/backup

and then change the backup directory from Deja-dup Settings and try restoring...

TO CHANGE SETTINGS-

System Settings>>  Backup >> Storage >>  Select "local folder" >> select the path as for my e.g "/home/username/backup"

The media being external might be causing problems...

Comment: Why would deja-dup read corrupted data from the external drive, but copying it to an internal drive (assuming `/home` *is* on an internal drive) succeed? If there's a problem with the external media, why wouldn't it affect the file copy operation the same way?

Comment: I am not saying that the External device might be corrupted.
But if the path set in the settings is not proper it might be a problem.Also,sometimes i have faced weird issues with some files,etc that were solved by bringing them into the home folder.
I am not saying my answer will work 100%.
I've just suggested to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I can recover a subset of the data, directly using duplicity, the way of doing that is the following.

Check on your manifest files on the backup folder the paths to the files on the backup, and you can restore folder by folder, in order to avoid the file/folder that raises the error.

The command is the following:

```
duplicity -t 1D --file-to-restore <folder or file without / at the begining> file://<path to the backup with / at the begining> </path/to/restore> --no-encryption -v8
```

And you can put `--ignore-errors``at the end of the command in order to try recovery all ignoring errors but it is not recommended.